# select a node in treeview programmatically in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, treeview

i have load a tree view. i want to Traverse treeview node and expand & select a node. Expand is working fine. but select a node is not working.

```
private void Traverse(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string findtext) 
        {
          foreach (TreeNode node in nodes) 
            {
                if (node.Text.ToString().Trim() == findtext)
                {
                    node.Expand();
                    node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node.NextNode;                    

                    //tvwStructureTree.SelectedNode = this.tvwStructureTree.Nodes[node.Index];
//Select a node in Treeview tvwStructureTree But not working
                    tvwStructureTree.SelectedNode = node; 
                    node.TreeView.Focus(); 
                }
                Traverse(node.Nodes, findtext); 
            } 

        }
```

Its in windows application.

Comment: What node do you want to select?  Not node.NextNode I imagine.  What is tvwStructureTree?  Try node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node.Nodes[0];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure what's your issue is. [TreeView.SelectedNode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) is the correct property.

> When you set this property, the specified node is scrolled into view
>   and any parent nodes are expanded so that the specified node is
>   visible.
>
> When the parent node or any ancestor node of the selected node is
>   collapsed either programmatically or through user action, the
>   collapsed node becomes the selected node.

Make sure that the `node.TreeView` is the correct TreeView instance.

```
node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node.NextNode;
```

[TreeView.HideSelection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hideselection.aspx) is another property that might useful for you.

> When this property is set to false, selected nodes in the TreeView
>   control remain highlighted in a different color than the current
>   selection color when the TreeView control loses focus. You can use
>   this property to keep items that are selected by the user visible when
>   the user clicks a different control on the form or moves to a
>   different window.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My form's ctor is given the test of a node to select.Finding the correct node was not a problem, but the tree didn't show the node as selected, since the tree control didn't have focus. merely had to use `Form.ActiveControl = myTreecontrol;` before setting `myTreecontrol.SelectedNode`

Answer (score 0):

I tested exactly your own code and worked fine, both find and selection the node!
without any particular property setting for my treeview!
by the way I am using .Net 3.5 and VS 2008